# CiviMail Two Column Responsive Template no longer responsive?

Tags: civimail

About a month ago our email newsletter based upon the default two column responsive template that's included within Civi Core stopped appearing correctly (in single column) in the Android Outlook app.

All of my previous emails also displayed differently too, reverting to the same two column layout as I expect to see on my desktop. Whats more the white link text on my blue button reverted to standard hyperlink blue.

I've just tested default template by copying the code from the demo site and got the same results so assume something has changed in the Outlook App.

Does anybody have any ideas on how to rectify this?